# If $σ$ is an exact differential $1$-form on the plane, then the form $ω=σ+xdy$ is not exact

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

> If $σ$ is an exact differential $1$-form on the plane, then prove that  the form $ω=σ+xdy$ is not exact.

In the previous part of the question we have calculated the integral of the differential $ω_1=x \Bbb d y$ over the ellipse $r(t)=\{x=2 \cos t, y=\sin t, \space  0<t<2\pi\}$, giving the answer $2\pi$, so I think it might have something to do with this? But I'm unsure how to start this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sigma =d \phi$ is exact, its integral over the ellipse will be zero (by Stokes's theorem: the ellipse bounds a streched-disk $D$ that's a $2$-chain, and $$
\int_{\partial D} d \phi = \int_{D} d^2 \phi = 0.
$$

Now you can check: if $\omega$ were exact, its integral over $\partial D$ would also be zero. But because the integral of $x ~dy$ is *not* zero, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Without using integration, but simply differential calculus: if $\sigma$ is exact and $\omega$ were too, then their difference $\omega - \sigma = x \Bbb d y$ would also be exact. For a trained eye this is clearly not true, but a beginner could use [Poincaré's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma): the interior of the ellipse is contractible (in fact it is convex, and therefore star-shaped) so any exact differential on it should be closed, i.e. $\Bbb d (x \Bbb d y) = 0$, which is equivalent to $\Bbb d x \wedge \Bbb d y = 0$ which is blatantly false.